# Can I run Observable at my local machine?

Tags: observablehq

Can I run [Observable](https://beta.observablehq.com/) at my local machine?

I don't find the install instuctions at official site.

Is this https://github.com/observablehq/notebook-runtime repo are core for run a local server?

Answer (score 5):

There's a [thread in our forum about this](https://talk.observablehq.com/t/private-installations/501), but to summarize:

- You can host your Observable notebooks elsewhere by using the [open source runtime](https://beta.observablehq.com/@jashkenas/downloading-and-embedding-notebooks) and export feature
- The Observable application doesn't have a version that runs online or is open source or installable.

Comment: First item: now, it is running without "beta." at https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/downloading-and-embedding-notebooks